# how to dissolve a polyline in R

Tags: r, gis, polyline, r-sf, r-sp

I have a large polyline shapefile that needs to be dissolved. However, the examples online only relate to polygons not polylines for example `gUnaryUnion`. I am reading in my shapefile using `st_read` from the `sf` package. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Union is not a well defined operation on lines - what is your expected result?

Comment: I managed to achieve what I needed using `st_combine`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, one option is to use `dplyr`.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# get polyline road data
temp_shapefile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017//ROADS/tl_2017_06075_roads.zip", temp_shapefile)
temp_dir <- tempdir()
unzip(temp_shapefile, exdir = temp_dir)

sf_roads <- read_sf(file.path(temp_dir,'tl_2017_06075_roads.shp'))
```

Use the RTTYP field to reduce the polyline from ~4000 unique segments to 6 segments.

```
sf_roads_summarized <- sf_roads %>%
  group_by(RTTYP) %>%
  summarize()
```

Answer (score 0):

I manged to achieve this by using `st_combine`.